# Compiling Selenium script using PyInstaller, getting TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The following is a truncated version of my code, which runs perfectly using Jupyter Notebook. I'm looking to have it compiled into an .exe, using Pyinstaller.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
import os, sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as ec


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("www.google.com")


wait_proxy = input("Press any key to exit...")
```

I added the `resource_path` function by referencing some posts on Stack Overflow, but am not too sure whether it is truly required.

Unfortunately, I get the error as below:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder> pyinstaller Simple.py
78 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
78 INFO: Python: 3.8.0
78 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
78 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Simple.spec
78 INFO: UPX is not available.
78 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder']
78 INFO: checking Analysis
93 INFO: checking PYZ
93 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
109 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\build\Simple\PYZ-00.pyz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Simple.spec", line 18, in <module>
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 128, in assemble
    self.code_dict = {
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 129, in <dictcomp>
    key: strip_paths_in_code(code)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 652, in strip_paths_in_code
    consts = tuple(
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 653, in <genexpr>
    strip_paths_in_code(const_co, new_filename)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 660, in strip_paths_in_code
    return code_func(co.co_argcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount, co.co_nlocals, co.co_stacksize,
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

My spec file is as below:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Simple.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Simple',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Simple')
```

Answer (score 3):

pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz

Direct install the latest version can be compatible with python 3.8

Comment: No problem @Huzoor

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.8, try downgrading as pyinstaller doesn't support all new python versions

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to the most pertinent reason that help most with being able to successfully compile a few days back.